# Div in React doesn't get the maximum size

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Having a React app with this structure:

**index.js**

```
...

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider
    store=...
  >
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App>
           //other components
      </App>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**App.js**

```
export default (props) => {
  return (
    <div style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
     <div
        className='container'
        style={{
          width: '100vw',
          height: '100vh',
          paddingBottom: '32px',
          paddingLeft: '37px',
          paddingRight: '37px',
          paddingTop: '20px',
          backgroundColor: 'green',
        }}
      >
        {props.children}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

container class contains:

```
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 1100vw;
}
```

My question is: why isn't the green as big as the red one? (plus/minus padding, doesn't matter)

I tried width: 100%, 100wh, auto, etc. No one worked. I want that element to be as big as its parent.

This is how it looks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNz24.jpg

I put a black rectangle over the app's data because it's not important in this case.

Comment: whats in the 'container' class ?

Comment: @klugjo updated the question with that info

Comment: if you look at the computed properties in the chrome inspector, what do you see ? click on width and check what is setting it

Comment: this is for red: https://i.imgur.com/6cxSRu7.png, this is for green: https://i.imgur.com/G9w08P9.png

Comment: I asked for the computed tab, but nevermind I saw the problem. Please look at my answer. Next time, think of using the debugger to see which class is setting the width of your element

Comment: Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) to show the issue happening.

Comment: In `.container` class you have `1100vw;` is that a typo? Did you mean `100vw;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your container class is adding a

```
max-width: 960px
```

to your green rectangle

You can either remove the `container` class or add

```
maxWidth: '100vw'
```

to the styles of your green div

Answer (score 1):

The property you are looking for is `vw` not `wh`. So changing `width: '100wh'` to `width: '100vw'` should solve your problem.

Comment: it was a typo in my question, in code it is like that ans still doesn't work. updated the question too about that typo

Answer (score 0):

The width units you are using are not right: try with **vw** or **vh** instead of **wh**.

You can check it at [MDN - CSS values and units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units)

Note: I have test it, after you fix de units, and the App.js works

Comment: it was a typo in my question, in code it is like that ans still doesn't work. updated the question too about that typo

Comment: I have test it, after you fix de units, and the App.js works. Perhaps you have something else wich is changing the styles. But as an inline style it should have prevalence over others. Here is my example: https://react-xrbl31.stackblitz.io

Comment: I'm trying to access your link but that loading circle is not stopping

Comment: Sorry, perhaps it was not saved, try with: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xrbl31